# How to change the color of inactive/disabled title/subtitle in ListTile Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I have a problem with changing the color of title/subtitle/leading of the disabled/inactive ListTile in Flutter.

My widget looks like this:
[image: ListTile Widget]

ListTile has a trailing Checkbox and it's checked. And the color of title/subtitle is light blue. I want to change this color, but don't know how. I tried to change it with ThemeData:

```
ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      subtitle1: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey[500],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

But it works only for unchecked Checkbox, after it's checked the title/subtitle becomes light blue, but I want it to be grey :( Where does thic color come from? What else I can try? I think I have this problem since I upgraded Flutter to 3.24.0, before that everything was fine. I am on Flutter Web and unfortunatelly can't use DevTool Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found a solution, but I think there could be another one, maybe with ThemeData, so I could define the color for every ListTile widget and don't use an additional widget to change it.

It's possible to change the color of inactive title/subtitle/leading with ListTileTheme like this:

```
ListTileTheme(
  selectedColor: Colors.grey,
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list_outlined),
    title: Text('Title'),
    subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
                  ),
              );
```

So basically I have to wrap ListTile with a ListTileTheme and use selectedColor property and it does the job! The color of inactive title/subtitle/leading changes.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CheckboxListTile of flutter try to create a custom ListTile using row in flutter for example :

```
Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [

Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.white),
 Expanded(
 child: AutoSizeText(
  data,
  maxLines: 1,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: white,
  ),
  )
),
 Checkbox(
value: _serachSelectList.contains(data),
onChanged: (bool value) {
  setState(() {
    if (value) {
      _serachSelectList.add(data);
      setState((){ default_color = selected_color });
    } else {
      _serachSelectList.remove(data);
      setState((){ default_color = unselected_color });
    }
  });
},
checkColor: Colors.green,
activeColor: Colors.transparent,
 materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
),

]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very creative, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution and I want to use already existing Flutter widgets. I just want to change the color of inactive title/subtitle, I know it's defined somewhere and I just waht to find it and change, so building a new widget seems like not the best solution for me.

Comment: you can set color of leading icon title and subtitle and also there is activeColor property in checkBoxListTile which can also be updated

Comment: Oh I didn't know the CheckBoxListTile widget exists, I'll take a closer look at it, thanks. But in my case I use List Tile widget and the Checkbox widget is a child of trailing property of ListTile.

Comment: ok, actually based on your design i thought you are using CheckBoxListTile

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation of ListTile, the disabled color is determined by the theme's disabled color, and there is no direct support to customize the disabled color as available support for the selected color. To work around this limitation, you can wrap the ListTile with a Theme widget and specify the desired disabled color within that.

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(disabledColor: YOUR_CHOICE_DISABLED_COLOR),
      child: ListTile(...),
      );
```